# Scala FlatMap and Applicative context boundaries yield compile error

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I'm doing some staff in Scala and came across a problem with `implicit` instances. Let's consider the following example:

```
import cats.{Applicative, FlatMap, Monad}
import cats.syntax.functor._
import cats.syntax.flatMap._
import cats.syntax.applicative._


class Test[F[_]: Monad] extends App{
  val t1 = ().pure[F]
  val t2 = ().pure[F]

  def testFlatApplicative: F[Unit] =
    for{
      _ <- t1
      _ <- t2
    } yield ()
}
```

This compiles fine. But since `cats.Monad[F[_]]` is declared as follows:

```
@typeclass trait Monad[F[_]] extends FlatMap[F] with Applicative[F]
```

I expected the following to work as well

```
import cats.{Applicative, FlatMap, Monad}
import cats.syntax.functor._
import cats.syntax.flatMap._
import cats.syntax.applicative._


class Test[F[_]: FlatMap : Applicative] extends App{
  val t1 = ().pure[F]
  val t2 = ().pure[F]

  def testFlatApplicative: F[Unit] =
    for{
      _ <- t1
      _ <- t2
    } yield ()
}
```

But it fails to compile with error:

```
Error:(16, 12) value map is not a member of type parameter F[Unit]
      _ <- t2
```

This is strange. `Apply` extends `Functor`...

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`class Test[F[_] : FlatMap : Applicative]` is desugared to

```
class Test[F[_]](implicit flatMap: FlatMap[F], applicative: Applicative[F])
```

If you desugar for-comprehension and syntaxes you'll see the problem:

```
def testFlatApplicative: F[Unit] = 
  FlatMap[F].flatMap(t1)(_ => 
    Functor[F].map(t2)(_ => ())
  )

Error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both value applicative in class Test of type cats.Applicative[F]
 and value flatMap in class Test of type cats.FlatMap[F]
 match expected type cats.Functor[F]
```

So you can resolve ambiguity manually:

```
def testFlatApplicative: F[Unit] = 
  FlatMap[F].flatMap(t1)(_ => 
    applicative.map(t2)(_ => ())
  )
```

or

```
def testFlatApplicative: F[Unit] = 
  FlatMap[F].flatMap(t1)(_ => 
    flatMap.map(t2)(_ => ())
  )
```

There is no such problem when you write `class Test[F[_]: Monad]` since you have single implicit.